# Minification and internationalization using angular-i18n

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, bundling-and-minification

I am using Laravel with elixir to concatenate, minify and version all third party scripts into `vendor-<elixir-version-hashid>.js`. Everything works fine, but the problem is with internationalization. I added `angular-i18n` library to the project but it seems that it expects only one of language files to be loaded because all of them declare a module with the same name

```
angular.module("ngLocale", [],
```

but with my Elixir approach I get all of language files in my vendor.js file, which leads to conflicts because now ngLocale is redeclared for each locale js file.

**What is the best approach to use angular-i18n together with minification? Should I create different vendor.js for each locale? Or should I leave locale files out of the minification process and instead use a custom gulp task to copy locale files to build folder? Any better approach?**

Important - I don't need dynamic language change, my app always performs full page reload when user changes his preferred language. I just need some way to make angular see the correct `ngLocale` when all third party .js files are being compiled into single vendor.js file.